# $request->all() empty for PUT method in LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel, request

In my localhost everything works fine, but in the server the Request it is empty for PUT method .. (Detail: for POST method it is working in both, local and server).

**My client "AngularJs" .....**

```
   $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: ******,
            data: $.param(vm.model),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response) {
.
.
.
```

**My route...**

```
Route::get('customer/list-registros/{param1}/{param2}', 'CustomerController@getListRegistros'); 
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
```

**My Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{       
   return $request->all(); // empty
}
```

---

I renamed the file "\bootstrap\cache\config.php".
My system it's hosted in Ipage .. using Cpanel.
Method POST works fine in my locahost and server... method PUT works in my localhost but DON'T works in the server

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML form also

Comment: Hi, I use Formlyjs to generate my Form ... All fields are created in JS

Comment: My Client is Angularjs ... so this is my Form HTML..        <form ng-submit="onSubmit()" name="form" novalidate >
        
         <formly-form model="model" fields="fields" options="options" form="form">
         </formly-form>
       </form>

Comment: did you get this to work?